# Insert comma in a string at a regular interval in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a String like this.

**Input:**

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

I need to insert comma after every forth letter. Is that possible in any of the oracle functions?

**Output:**

```
abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop
```

Comment: Fourth word or fourth letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "letter" (as implied by the examples), just use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(val, '(.{4})', '\1,')
```

Comment: Isn't there a SO Guideline, which suggests OP to try and attempt his question?

Comment: How do you understand these regular expressions. Where we could learn all of it ?

Comment: @user7952074 . . . There are probably a thousand on-line tutorials and guides to regular expressions.